# What range or variation should we expect from gyroscope in a helicopter?

Tags: helicopter

I need to measure the angular variation of a helicopter. Hence, I am looking for a 3-axis gyroscope? However, what kind of specification the gyroscope should have, like sample rate etc? Therefore, I want to know how the angular velocity changes (in any axis) in helicopter. I need to know the range only.

Any reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Angular displacement due to flight manoeuvres?

Comment: @Koyovis yes, in addition while moving in land in wheels etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3-DoF magnetic gyroscopes are a dime a dozen nowadays, together with 3-DoF accelerometers, magnetic field sensors, and GPS position transducers. These are in mobile phones now, tiny and frugal with electricity. A google search for *"9-dof position acceleration gyroscope"* results in a lot of options.

For the sampling rate: this needs to be at least twice the frequency of the fastest vibration - more is better, since a frequency at half the sampling rate shows up as a triangular wave.

[image: from the linked site]

For the frequency range of angular displacement, [this article](http://www.autospeed.com/cms/article.html?&title=Measuring-wheel-suspension-rates&A=113057) might be of interest. It shows vibration data of a car driving over the road, using an iPhone to measure the vibrations. The article mentions a sprung frequency (inside the vehicle) of 1 - 5 Hz. A helicopter usually has higher inertia than a car, so sprung frequency should be lower. If you take 0 - 10 Hz as a baseline for the range, you should be safe. The ground reaction angular frequency range is always higher than the airborne one: responses in the hover are measured in seconds, not in Hz.

[image]

Above graph shows pitch response of an example helicopter, from Prouty, Helicopter Performance, Stability and Control. A helicopter with a rotor mounted on top is unstable in the hover, but in order to still be controllable for human pilots the response frequency may not be too high - it turns out that humans can comfortably control instabilities with a time period in the order of around 10 sec. The military have requirements for the stability response in [MIL-H-8501A](http://everyspec.com/MIL-SPECS/MIL-SPECS-MIL-H/MIL-H-8501A_7645/)

Comment: "The ground reaction angular frequency range is always higher than the airborne one." Is there any reference or insight to it? This is the most important insights I was looking for.

Comment: Yes you're right, that is a bit of a sweeping statement. Have expanded the answer.